# How do I receive the coordinates from a SQLview? Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, postgresql, openlayers, openlayers-3

Using Openlayers 3:

I have a SQLview and i want to plan a route from my own location to the resulting feature (it's always one feature) of the SQLview. With the SQL view I get the results back as a WMS and I just need the coordinates of that feature with it to plan the route. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is WFS (Web Feature Service), not WMS (Web Map Service).

With WFS you can retrieve, from the server, the features (geometry + attributes), instead of an image like WMS.

To achieve this in OL, you can use VectorLayer ([OL Docs - VectorLayer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html)).

Check this links,

[OL Examples - WFS Extent](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html)

[OL Examples - WFS Filter](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html)